# Cannot access HAProxy stats page

Tags: docker, haproxy

I am running HAproxy as a container on my local ubuntu machine based on this guide:

https://hub.docker.com/_/haproxy/

I am now trying to access the `stats` page in my browser with:

http://localhost:8443/haproxy?stats

http://localhost/haproxy?stats

https://localhost:8443/haproxy?stats

But all the above gives: `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

In my **haproxy.cfg** file I have:

```
global
  maxconn 1000

  ca-base /var/lib/haproxy/certs
  crt-base /var/lib/haproxy/certs
  tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048

defaults
  maxconn 1000
  timeout connect 130s
  timeout client 130s
  timeout client-fin 111s
  timeout server 130s
  timeout server-fin 111s
  timeout http-request 130s
  timeout http-keep-alive 300s

  # Long timeout for WebSocket connections.
  timeout tunnel 1h

  log     global 
  mode    http
  option forwardfor
  option http-server-close
  option  httplog

  stats enable
  stats uri /stats
  stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
  stats auth user:password


frontend haproxy
  bind :8443 ssl crt frontend/server.pem  
  reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http
  default_backend myapp

backend myapp
  server myapp localhost:9000
```

Also it seems the URL used in:

```
backend myapp
  server myapp localhost:9000
```

does not really have an effect. If I change to :

```
backend myapp
  server myapp 199.17.0.2:9000
```

I can still access **myapp** on localhost:9000.  So what is the purpose of specifying an URL in the backend section?

I run **myapp** with:

```
docker run -d --name myapp -p 9000:9000 -p 9092:9092 myapp
```

Based on below suggestion/answer I run **HAProxy** with:

```
docker run -d --name my-running-haproxy -p 8443:8443 my-haproxy:1.7
```

And I can now access stats page on:

https://localhost:8443/stats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace localhost with your container's ip address since haproxy is running inside your docker container and not directly on your machine. Or you could map the 8443 port inside your docker container to the exact same port on your linux machine. Then you'll be able to access it in browser using http://localhost:8443

Comment: Its the 'myapp' where I have currently specified 'localhost'. HAproxy is set to :8443 so do you mean in the frontend or backend?

Comment: What I was trying to say is that haproxy is running inside a docker container not on your local ubuntu machine. So localhost, in your case is your ubuntu machine and not your docker container. The haproxy listening port, from inside the docker container should map to the same or another port on your local ubuntu. Or you can try to access haproxy using your docker container's private ip address. It has nothing to do with the frontend nor the backend configuration of your haproxy

Comment: Ok but I can access 'myapp' - which is also started as a container - on localhost:9000. But I guess that comes from the '-p 9000:9000 -p 9092:9092' as part of the docker run command? If that is the case then I should be able to do similar to access HAproxy from localhost?

Comment: Exactly. You should map your haproxy port to a local port same way you did it for your app. That’s what I was trying to say even from the start